# Unable to post - login problems with Area 51 ... again

Tags: bug, area-51, login

I recently signed up for Area 51 with my stackexchange network account/ID, verified the account and logged in.  I see the main page https://area51.stackexchange.com/ where I confirm that I am logged in.  I click on the discuss link on the black menubar at the top, which takes me to the discussion zone. From here I click on ask question, which asks me to add  a login even though I have already logged in with my stackexchange ID.  Here if I choose the stackexchange login option then it takes me back to the main page, from where the cycle begins again.

Comment: Are you sure you have cookies enabled? Which browser are you using? If you use a different browser does it fail as well? You say *again* but I don't see a previous post from you. When did this happen before?

Comment: Using Firefox 34.0 and yes cookies are enabled.  I use some plugins such as Adblock Plus and HTPPS everywhere.  Could they cause any problems?

Comment: Yes, https everywhere is a known culprit as the SE network doesn't support https fully.

Comment: By 'again' I was referring to other posts about  login problems for Area 51.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215629/unable-to-log-into-careers-2-0-with-https-everywhere-plugin

Comment: The browser console shows the following error:

Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "gravatar.com/avatar/…; 

But I don't have the same problem with other stackexchange sites on which I can log on without any problems.

Comment: Don't use https on Area51 is the only solution I'm afraid... remember that Area51 is based on an older in-compatible codebase than the rest of the SE sites which makes me believe that a fix would take more than 6-8 weeks, if it gets fixed at all.

Comment: I've similar problem with Epic browser on which it doesn't work. At area51.SE it works fine (shows as logged-in), but when redirected to discuss.area51.SE, then it doesn't work (I'm not logged in). When trying to log-in again, I'm back to area51.SE again where it was working fine, but still not at discuss.area51.SE.

Comment: @kenorb Logging in on meta.stackexchange.com should get you into discuss.A51.

Comment: Could it be similar to this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264108/if-youve-got-google-you-dont-seem-to-mean-much-anymore

Answer (score 1):

It seems registering and logging in on http://meta.stackexchange.com first solves the problem as suggested by [@Adam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245828/unable-to-post-login-problems-with-area-51-again#comment890164_245828).

Comment: Glad that helped. To be clear, this is basically just a workaround. The actual issue is kind of thorny to solve, but on my list to get to as soon as I have some time.

Comment: This does not work for me. How can this still be an issue, after a little over 2 years from the first post ?

Answer (score 1):

Logging on [openid.stackexchange.com](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login) first may help. Otherwise make sure that cookies aren't blocked in your browser for [Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

In Epic, to unblock ads/tracking cookies (which are blocked by default), disable *Block Ads & Trackers*.

[image: Epic, cookies, Block Ads & Trackers, Area51]