# Can't join Area 51 discussions

Tags: bug, status-review, area-51, login, sign-up

I want to join the [Area 51 (Stack Exchange site) Discussion Zone community](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com). But when I click the "join this community", the page displays a message:

> Completing log in to Area 51.
> You will be redirected automatically.

Then it redirects me to Area 51, not the Discussion Zone.

I looked at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245828/unable-to-post-login-problems-with-area-51-again), which suggests using `http`, not `https`, but my browser just redirects me to the `https` version of the site.

I've also tried to click the link in the Area 51 header, (it's called discuss), but it just redirects me to the un-joined Area 51 Discussion Zone.

So... How do I join?

Comment: Area 51 signup seems to have been broken for a very long time, by my understanding. There are related posts on Area 51 meta [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29933/223114) and [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32831/223114).

Comment: Never ming. After playing around with my cookies and different browsers, I finally got it!

Comment: You should answer your own question and tell people exactly what you did, because other people are still experiencing the problem (including me - I get a "No user found" error when I try to join).

Comment: @Stuckat1337 I know this isn't helpful, but I don't exactly know! Just played around deleting my cookies and trying different browsers and suddenly I had an account! It's recognized a one of *my* accounts, not a separate one, like some of the questions I saw were complaining about. I figured I shouldn't post an answer as it was probably just a fluke and I don't know what made it happen.

Comment: Has this since been resolved? I see [your profile on Area 51 Discussions here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/223888/ben-the-coder).

Comment: @V2Blast See my [comment above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390072/cant-join-area-51-discussions#comment1302223_390072).